# How can I add MVC exceptions to my Azure table storage application

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

My group has action methods in MVC and these methods have coding to catch exceptions. Right now they are caught and lost. What we would like to do is to catch these and then log them. But I am not sure how to do this with Azure table storage. Is there some accepted way to do this?

```
    public bool Create(Account account)
    {
        if (!ValidateAccount(account))
            return false;
        try
        {
            _accountRepository.AddOrUpdate(account);
        }
        catch
        {
            // NEED TO ADD EXCEPTION TRACKING HERE
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is enable [diagnostics monitoring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433048.aspx) in your web role and [configure the DiagnosticsTraceListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh411522.aspx).

Then in you code all you will need to call is call `System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError(message);`